# Text in cell losing its formatting when reference from one sheet to another

Tags: excel

I have some text in a list of cells in an excel sheet A which are the values of a dropdown list in sheet B. Part of the text in a cell is underlined.

However, in sheet B from the dropdown list, when i selected the cell that has part of the text underlined, the underlined formatting is not shown on sheet B.

Any ideas why?

Comment: would you mind showing a screenshot of this?

Comment: oh how do i show a screen shot here?

Comment: just press *print* on your keyboard, when you have a scenario in excel ready, which shows your problem - then open paint or a equivalent graphics-tool, paste it, crop it, save it, use the little picture-icon to upload it into your answer.

Comment: Validation lists don't copy formatting from the source cell(s), only their values.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer (as provided by @Tim Williams):

> Validation lists don't copy formatting from the source cell(s), only their values.